# Trying to call an excel macro from an html app running javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I have written an app to read user input and write said input to a `.txt` file since it is easier for an excel macro to read.  I have already written a macro that reads from the text document and pushes that data to the excel worksheet. Is there any sure-fire way to run an excel macro from javascript?

Here is what I have tried:

```
    function RunMacro(objType) {
    switch (objType) {
        case "90":
            var fileName = "P:\\Engineering\\Generated Part Logs\\90-.xlsm";
            break;
        case "69":
            fileName = "P:\\Engineering\\Generated Part Logs\\69-.xlsm";
            break;
        case "66":
            fileName = "P:\\Engineering\\Generated Part Logs\\66-.xlsm";
            break;
        case "40":
            fileName = "P:\\Engineering\\Generated Part Logs\\40-.xlsm";
            break;
        case "30":
            fileName = "P:\\Engineering\\Generated Part Logs\\30-.xlsm";
            break;
        case "09":
            fileName = "P:\\Engineering\\Generated Part Logs\\09-.xlsm";
            break;
        case "02":
            fileName = "P:\\Engineering\\Generated Part Logs\\02-.xlsm";
            break;
    }
    var bookName = fileName.substring(35);
    alert(bookName);
    var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    Excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
    Excel.Visible = true;
    Excel.Run("Sheet1.ImportPartData1");
}
```

Am I naming the macro correctly here? Or is this just the wrong way to access an excel macro from a javascript app?

Comment: My initial error was identifying a file incorrectly in the macro..

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the file name:

```
Excel.Run("'fileNameHere.xlsm'!Sheet1.ImportPartData1")
```

Comment: I have tried that and that doesnt seem to work for some reason.

Comment: Can you show exactly what you tried?  What exactly happened when you ran your code?

Comment: I actually managed to run the macro without referencing the file name. I think it worked since the macro name was just sheet1.import data1